# Frequency of Warp Core Ejections

Tags: star-trek

I was trying to find a comprehensive list of Warp Core Ejection events on the net and am coming up empty.

The best thing I found was:

[a link at memory-alpha(.org) centered around Voyager mentioning no other such event during a TV series.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_core_ejection_system)

I am having trouble with this, emotionally speaking, as I feel part of my childhood memory may have been fabricated via ESP.

Comment: Usually the problems have been because they're _unable_ to eject the core when it's about to breach/overload.  Perhaps your memory just has it backwards?  Do you have a specific scene in mind, that we may be able to pinpoint if you describe it?

Comment: You got to marvel at Federation ingenuity with Voyager - they replaced their warp core 4 times when over 50 years travel to the nearest StarFleet spacedock

Comment: @HorusKol not really. Once the warp core is ejected it's a simple matter of a shuttlecraft or two and some tractor beams to tractor it back into position and reinsert it if there's no damage to the core which would preclude doing so.

Comment: @Izkata: Yeah, I know there were countless instances when the warp core was jeopardized… I'm still finding it hard to believe that neither Scotty nor O'Brien ever actually had to go through with it on TNG. Could be, but no, unfortunately, my memory these years later is far too fuzzy to point to a specific episode/event...

Comment: @NOTjust--user4304 Scotty never doing it doesn't surprise me; the technology in TOS wasn't very well defined.  And it would've been Geordi on TNG, if that helps your memory.  O'Brien on DS9.

Comment: @Dr.JKL - the warp core was ejected because it was about to explode... and did explode after the ejection - nothing to recover

Comment: @Izkata oh right, Scotty just made a handful of guest appearances on TNG. On the Other hand, I just clicked through the descriptions of TNG eps. on StarTrek.com, and though there were a couple breaches, and a new drive installed at one point (w/o explanation in the summary)(?) there were no ejections. There were some close calls however, see [this memory alpha article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_core_breach). I don't have time to read all descriptions of all movie trek episodes atm…, so I can't verify it matches exactly w/ Memory-alpha. Though I'm sure those guys are die hard fans.

Comment: @HorusKol In the list linked to in the question, in the first two, the core was ejected but simply recovered by shuttlecraft; the third wasn't the real Voyager; and I don't recall the outcome of the fourth

Comment: @Izkata - okay, makes a bit of sense.

Comment: @Izkata it was similarly recovered via another craft after a non-emergency ejection to be used in exchange for human hostage Cpt. Janeway.

Comment: “I'm still finding it hard to believe that neither Scotty nor O'Brien ever actually had to go through with it on TNG.” I can imagine Scotty saying “Eject the warp core? If you’ve got to that stage, laddie, ye went wrong a long time before.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a good list of Warp Core ejections on the [Star Trek Wikia](http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_many_times_in_star_trek_history_has_the_warp_core_been_ejected)

There are seven specific instances of Federation warp cores being **successfully** ejected, twice in the Film canon and five times in Star Trek : Voyager.

1. The Enterprise-E warp core was ejected to seal the [subspace tear](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Subspace_tear) in "[Star Trek : Insurrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection)".
2. The Enterprise crew ejected *several* warp cores to create a shockwave they could use to escape the black hole that formed in the Narada in the 2009 movie "[Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28film%29)"
3. By Chakotay's spirit inhabiting Torres (in order to prevent Voyager from entering a nebula) in "[Cathexis](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cathexis_%28episode%29)"
4. To prevent a breach due to a build-up of tachyon particles in VOY "[Day of Honor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Day_of_Honor_%28episode%29)"
5. By the Doctor (to barter for Janeway's release) in "[Renaissance Man](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Renaissance_Man_%28episode%29)"
6. The [duplicate](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Silver_Blood) Voyager ejected their warp core to try to get the attention of the real Voyager crew in "[Course: Oblivion](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Course:_Oblivion_%28episode%29)".
7. The 2nd Delta Flyer ejected its warp core in "[Drive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Drive_%28episode%29)" because the fuel converter had been sabotaged.

[image: Voyager Warp Core Ejection]

For the record, although the ejection system is described in detail in the "TNG Technical Manual", the Next-Generation crew failed on at least <s>14</s> [8 separate occasions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/204008/20774) to eject the core (including parallel universes).

[image: Warp Core Ejection procedures]

Comment: I know that with I have a crack of tear in something, I want to use high explosives to seal it too. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I rather think that it's analogous to using explosives to close a tunnel

Comment: @Richard: Let's blow up all the nothing so it collapses around the void!  Sadly, it makes 'sense' in the Star Trek way of thinking.

Comment: Except that the existence of  virtual particles and vacuum energy would suggest that the void is anything but empty

Comment: Let's not get wrapped around the axle with our metaphors ;-) "Tear" is hardly a scientific description for a disruption of subspace, and "seal" is anything but a technical term for restoring equilibrium, so it's entirely possible that an anti-matter explosion will do what they want, even if it doesn't fit into the metaphor.

Comment: How dare you spoil our fun with your "facts" and "logic". For shame...

Comment: @Richard "… Next-Generation crew failed on at least 14 separate occasions to eject the core (including parallel universes)." Ohhhh…. yeah. So perhaps that's what I was thinking of! Thanks Richard! I'm in the same universe with the rest of you after all...