# Failed warp core ejections

Tags: star-trek, warp

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46833/3823) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43193/frequency-of-warp-core-ejections) claims that there are 14 different failed warp core ejections depicted.

> *For the record, although the ejection system is described in detail in
>   the "TNG Technical Manual", the Next-Generation crew failed on at
>   least 14 separate occasions to eject the core (including parallel
>   universes).*

On which occasions were these failed ejections?   What's the basis of the claim this was depicted 14 times?

Comment: One would think they would have made it easier to eject the core after 14 instances where ejection failed...I'd have a long talk with the chief engineer after that...

Comment: Things happen a little differently in space than they do on the drawing board: https://gph.is/2RdnBvF

Comment: Not sure I am understanding your question correctly - do you want to know a list of these failed ejections? or What a failed ejection is?  Obviously if you have already taken significant damage - some random systems are not going to perform as advertised - there might even be a case where the enterprise is being boarded and the captain finds that the self destruct system has failed.

Comment: @enumaris - tough call - when most of them happened in time loops or alternative universes - record keeping becomes a problem in universe!

Comment: @Andrew I'm asking to identify the claimed 14 occurences.

Comment: Really, you wouldn't design it this way. You would obviously want your core on some kind of spring held down by some kind of electromagnet so that if your safety system ever lost power the antimatter core would automatically be ejected  as opposed to stuck in the ship to explode. The writers of TNG were not engineers.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming each time the core breached there was at least some attempt to dump it, the Enterprise-D failed to eject their core **8** times on screen.

- **TNG: True Q** (Unable to eject before it exploded)
- **TNG: Cause and Effect** (Three times, one for each failed loop)
- **TNG: Timescape** (After a breach caused by aliens)
- **TNG: Parallels** (Actually a parallel universe Enterprise)
- **ST: Generations** (Twice, once in each time loop)

Comment: So what's the basis for this claim of 14?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Dunno. I've edited it to read the more accurate figure. Probably I was conflating *all* warp core ejection failures with just those from TNG

Comment: Can we enumerate the remaining 6?

Answer (score -2):

In star trek voyager basics part 1
Captain Janeway tried to set the Self Destruct but it failed.
Janeway to computer.
Initiate self-destruct sequence.
Authorization: Janeway-pi-1-1-0.
Set at ten minutes.
(Computer says) Unable to initiate self-destruct sequence due to damage to secondary command processors.

Comment: OP is asking about a claim about the TNG (Enterprise) crew, not Voyager or DS9 or any other Federation ship

Comment: Maybe the same problem happened on tng before. I'm new to this website and I will learn to read the questions better.

Comment: I always make it a point of saying the question out loud (or at least reading it out in my head) before I press the "answer" button. It's the best way to avoid answering the question you want to answer rather than the question asked :-)

Comment: I think so the question title is at the top of the screen then there's a section where the person has written the question and then there are all the replies.